# How do I communicate with the API running on port 9345 in a default RKE2 deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, security, rke

So I've been playing around with RKE2 to see if it fits my security needs and im trying to figure out what port 9345 is, and how to communicate with it manually.

So far, I found out that its supposed to be RKEs "Management API"...

I tried doing manual (HTTP) API-Requests against that port and keep getting "404 Not Found" as a response. Its not responding to normal Kubernetes requests either.

I have googled quite a while but I give up, as I can't find anything after a few hours of research.

A pointer to appropriate documentation, or additional info otherwise would be greatly appreciated.